# Centre on decimal when brackets present

Tags: horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I have a table column where I'm centring all the numbers on the decimal using `dcolumn` and I'm finding that if a number is in brackets and no decimal point is present then it will align on the right edge of the last bracket instead. Without brackets everything is correctly aligned. Is there an easy way to get this to align properly? A simplified version of my table is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
    [0]\\\relax
    [1.23]\\\relax
    [12.34]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is what is looks like with and without the brackets. I want the right column to be aligned like the left one.

[image: table alignment bug]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A clunky solution seems to be to replace every ````]```` bracket of integers with ````\rlap{]}````. It works, but is not particularly feasible for large quantities of numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-pre={[},table-space-text-post={]},
    table-align-text-pre=false,table-align-text-post=false]
}
 0    &   [0]     \\
 1.23 &   [1.23]  \\
12.34 &   [12.34]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make `]` act like `.` and force the alignment point, re-inserting itself at the right place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\makeatletter

\def\DC@centre#1#2#3{%
  \let\DC@end\DC@endcentre
  \uppercase{\def~}{$\egroup\setbox\tw@=\hbox\bgroup${#2}}%
  \uccode`\~=`\]%
  \uppercase{\def~}{$\egroup\setbox\tw@=\hbox\bgroup${]}}%
  \setbox\tw@=\hbox{${\phantom{{#2}}}$}%
  \setbox\z@=\hbox\bgroup$\mathcode`#1="8000 
  \mathcode`]="8000 }


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
    [0]\\\relax
    [1.23]\\\relax
    [12.34]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```